# How to run multiple executables with Azure cloud services - Function apps?

Tags: azure, cloud

I'm dealing with a legacy piece of software, totally not cloud friendly.
The local workflow is as follows:

- Run Software1
- Software1 creates some helper files to be used by Software2
- Software2 runs and generates a result file

Software2 is a simulation model compiled as executable.
I now need to run hundreds of simulations and since this software doesn't even support multi-threading I'm looking at running it in the cloud. I have little to none experience with cloud computing. Our company mainly works with Azure but I don't have a problem using AWS or another cloud computing service.

What I'm thinking as possible solution is:

- Run a virtual machine that runs Software1
- Software1 creates several folders. Each folder contains all the necessary files to perform a single simulation.
- Each folder is loaded to a blob storage folder
- A Function app is triggered by the blob storage folder creation and a run is performed for each folder by running Software2
- Once Software2 is done with the simulation, the function app copies the result file back to the blob storage, in the same folder of the corresponding run.

I tested the Function App and it does what I need but I'm not quite sure how run it several times in parallel. Do you have any suggestion on how to achieve this? Or maybe I should be using something different than function apps.

Thank you in advance for your help,
Guido

Comment: Can you clarify: Soft1 will create one blob (job) or multiple blobs (work files for a job)? Soft2 needs to be triggered multiple times for a job or for each work file?

Comment: sorry, it is not clear. See edited question.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood this correctly, you want to run this Function App multiple times in parallel to "simulate" parallel execution. I think you need to look at Event Grid and re-think your architecture.

Comment: Yes, basically I have 1 executable and many configurations. That's what the helper files are. I need to run that exe for each configuration (set of helper files).

I'll look into Event Grid.

Comment: You need a messaging or an event backplane to get this thing working. I've done something like this before, where I've had a command app create a large group of json files, place them into a directory where a second sub-system picks these up as config files and executes them. The way to architect this is to use blobstorage and Event Grid and then the have the Function App as the Subscriber to execute your Function App logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a blob trigger, your function will be triggered each time you'll be making an operation in the blob container.  If 1 file = 1 run for Software2, a blob trigger is OK and Azure will scale and run your function in parallel.  The issue is that Software2 needs to write the results back in blob, creating new triggers.

Another way would be to have Software1 send a message to Storage Queue or Service Bus or an event with Event Grid and have your function be triggered by that. You then would write a Durable function using the "Fan out/fan in" pattern to run Software2 in parallel.

You can also look at creating parallel branches in Logic App.